# How do I use mblen()?

Tags: c, multibyte-functions

Here is some test code to help me understand multibyte character management.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char * line = malloc(1024);
    size_t n;

    getline(&line, &n, stdin);
    while (*line) {
        int offset = mblen(line, strlen(line));
        if (offset == -1) return 0;
        printf("%d\n", offset);
        line += offset;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As I understand it, if the user were to type "éléphant", my output should show 2 1 2 1 ...
However, it shows -1 for an `mblen` error, right from the first byte.
I gather it probably ain't a bug in these 2 lines of code, what must I do, what resources can I read to get a hint on what happens here?
Of course a `printf("%s", line)` would work (and does) work perfectly.

Comment: Maybe your application is not recognizing the é character for some reason. I'm currently trying to figure out why.

Comment: Works for me if I call `setlocale (LC_ALL,"");` at the start of `main`. Also I you should initialize `n`.

Comment: @user786653 Works for me too actually, but it did not return 2,1,2,1 like OP needed, maybe I have some sort of character encoding set wrong... You should probably post your setlocale function as an answer.

Comment: @JohnOdom: Your locale is probably set to iso-8859-1 rather than utf-8.

Comment: Thanks, setlocale was the thing. Appreciated. How do I vote the answer if it is a comment?

Comment: @pouzzler You can ask the comment writer to convert their comment to answer. And if they don't, and nobody else does either, then you can write answer yourself so you can accept it (better give it a few days).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer.

The details might depend on your exact execution environment, but I think the following should apply for most *NIX-systems.

[`mblen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mblen.html) depends on the current locale

> The behavior of this function is affected by the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale

The default locale on startup is the "C" locale (see [`setlocale`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setlocale.html)), which might not match what you're expecting. Conveniently you can call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` to set the locale to the "native" environment.

Note that calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` (as I originally wrote) changes more that you're possibly expecting, so be sure to read up on all things locale-related before doing that.